# Angular how to implement OAuth

Tags: javascript, angular, oauth

I have an Angular app which uses a websocket connection to interact with a server. Now I need to implement OAuth in third party service, however I cannot handle any events on new tab opened via `window.open(url)`.

The OAuth API redirects the window to my domain and returns token in URL query params. I need to catch this token to work with this. How can this be implemented?

---

```
const eHealthWind = window.open(msg.data.url);
console.log(eHealthWind.window);
    eHealthWind.onload = function () {
    eHealthWind.onpopstate = function (e) {
        console.log('pop', e);
    };
};
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: There is nothing to show. Just line which opens new tab. And another line which tries to apply EventListener to this window (as it occurred cannot be applied to tab opened with another domain)

Comment: @HenslerSoftware added this poor code. Not sure whether it will help somehow.

Comment: have you tried implementing new Subject and emit change (token) as observable, when you redirect to your domain? i can provide example of code but don't know if this will help you.

Comment: That's not me who is redirecting. That is a third party API. eHealth if be concrete. I need to open their page so that user authenticates then page is redirected to my domain and passes token in url params

Comment: well, if third party is redirecting to your component and token is inside of url you can create a route snapshot and inside of ngOnInit lifecycle hook you can sniff it and store it for handling.

Comment: Where am I suppose to get this route snapshot? I open this in another tab. In current tab I cannot do this due to app architecture constraints.

Comment: Use the canActivate method on your route that is redirected to and catch the token via the canActivate class and temporarily save it in the localstorage or wherever to work with in the mean time, access it via your component, do what you need to do and then clear it from localstorage :) I can post a code example of this if you like?

Comment: Nope. You don't read what I write.

Comment: i did read it. why not just open the oauth url in the same window since further functionality cannot continue until the user has authenticated?. once the user authenticates, you can easily grab the token using the canactivate method i mentioned above.

Comment: Because as I said there is no chance to leave current window. I work on websocket. Many useful things may run on it. If I navigate away I loose the sessions as well as all work that user may have done.

Comment: ok well in that case, get the third party to redirect to a specific url for this and include some state to identify user. then when that url is hit by the third party service via the redirect, post to your backend with the catched token and state and close that window. Now use the websocket to send the token to the original window and work from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a possible way:

```
     const loggedInPromise = new Promise((res) => {
       const eHealthWind = window.open(msg.data.url);

        const intervalId = setInterval(function() {
          try {
            res(eHealthWind.location.href);
            clearInterval(intervalId);
            eHealthWind.close();
          } catch (error) {

          }
        }, 1000);
      })

      loggedInPromise.then((urlWithToken) => { console.log(urlWithToken); })
```

Comment: Sorry, where does this `urlWithToken` go? I don't see any variable declaration. Am I missing it?

Comment: Edited the answer. You just resolve the promise with the href that should contain the token

Comment: I ran into my own problems. Was solving. Thanks for your answer. It works.

Comment: please change `cancelIntercal` into  `clearInterval` since the first one doesn't exist